# Get the maximum possible value after doing an addition

Tags: java, algorithm

My program takes a number and checks each digit, adds a 5 to it and generates a modified number. Now find the maximum modified value as result.

**Example:**

**Input:**

```
555
```

**Output:**

```
5510
```

**Explanation:**
All possible combinations are :

```
1055
5105
5510

Maximum in these is 5510.
```

**Example:**

```
Input : 444, output : 944.
```

**Constraints:** input number can range from 0 to 100000.

This is my code which is working for this example.

```
public static int process(int number) {
    int n = number;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (n == 0)
        return 5;
    while (n > 0) {
        list.add(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }

    int out = -1;
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int j = list.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            int e = list.get(j);
            if (i == j) {
                e += 5;
            }
            sb.append(e);
        }
        out = Math.max(out, Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()));
    }
    return out;
}
```

How to improve this code by reducing time complexity.

Comment: Asking for improvements to working code is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com. That being said, my immediate understanding of this problem is that there are 2 cases: 1) The numbers does only digits <=4, in that case replacing the left most digit with its +5 value is the correct solution. 2) The number does contain digits >= 5, in that case replacing the right most digit that is >= 5  with its +5 value will be the correct solution. eG if you take the number 145071 you replacing the 7 and getting 1450121 is the correct solution.

Comment: So I'd probably try just looping over the digits from last (right) to first (left) and as soon as you find one that is >= 5 you can stop the loop and know that is the one to replace, or if your loop finishes without finding a digit >=5 you know to replace the left most digit.

Answer (score 2):

If the number has any digits >= 5, choose the right-most such digit. Otherwise choose the left-most digit.

We must choose a digit >= 5 if such exists because that buys us an extra digit and grows the number by more vs any digit < 5 which doesn't get us an extra digit. We choose the right-most because our new number will be 1x and we want that 1 as far to the right as possible.

If all digits are < 5 then +5 will just increase whichever digit it's applied do, which we want done to our left-most digit.

So linear time in the number of digits: scan the digits for ones >= 5, and either modify the last such you find, or the first digit if you find none.

Comment: Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without `char`/`String`/`StringBuilder` may look like this:

- use a flag `found5` to detect the first occurrence of a `digit >= 5`
- when a first `digit >= 5` is detected, add 5, reset the flag, and use additional shift of a `power`
- in the main loop body, calculate the result by adding `power * digit`, divide n by 10, multiply `power` by 10 * shift
- when the loop is done, check for the flag and add 5 to the leftmost digit

```java
private static int numAnd5(int n) {
    boolean found5 = false;
    int result = 0;
    int power = 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        int shift = 1;
        int digit = n % 10;
        if (!found5 && digit >= 5) {
            found5 = true;
            digit += 5;
            shift = 10;
        }
        result += power * digit;
        power *= 10 * shift;
        n /= 10;
    }
    if (!found5) {
        result += 5 * Math.max(1, power / 10);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Tests:

```java
for (int x : new int[]{0, 1, 2, 7, 10, 14, 16, 61, 125, 153, 111, 145071, 4321023 }) {
    System.out.println(x + " -> " + numAnd5(x));
}
```

Output:

```
0 -> 5
1 -> 6
2 -> 7
7 -> 12
10 -> 60
14 -> 64
16 -> 111
61 -> 111
125 -> 1210
153 -> 1103
111 -> 611
145071 -> 1450121
4321023 -> 9321023
```

Answer (score -1):

The following should reduce it from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)` where `n` is the number of characters in the input.

Note that I do not know Java and do not have access to an IDE at the moment, so the following is untested C#/Java-like pseudocode:

```
public static int process(int number) {
    int n = number;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (n == 0)
        return 5;
    while (n > 0) {
        list.add(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }

    // convenient list of powers of 10
    List<Integer> powers = new ArrayList<>(list.size);
    n = 1;
    for (int i = powers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        powers[i] = n;
        n *= 10;
    }

    int out = -1;
    int top = 0;
    int bottom = number;
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int curr = list[i] * power[i];
        bottom -= curr;

        int newTop = top;
        int newCurr = (list[i]+5) * power[i];
        if (list[i]+5 > 9) {
            newTop *= 10;
        }

        out = Math.max(out, newTop + newCurr + bottom);
        top += curr;
    }
    return out;
}
```